# CPU with integrated GPU and motherboard with HDMI2.0 RGB 4K60 output

Tags: processor, motherboard

It has been years since most TV boxes support HDMI 2.0 4K60, but PCs with integrated GPU still doesn't support this well. In most cases, the chipsets support it, but the motherboard doesn't.

A problem of 4K30 is higher latency, which 4K60 solves. A problem of FHD is the image is not as sharp as 4K, and looks horrible on some TVs that do image processing (e.g. sharpness improvement) on non-native resolutions which may benefit videos, but will make a desktop image awful.

So, I need a DIY motherboard CPU with integrated CPU/GPU supporting RGB 4K60 over HDMI 2.0 and:

(1) Is a new platform that support DDR4 3000+

(2) Is low power, but not low performance (like the Intel Celeron N3150, for which running VM is real pain).

(3) (Optional) PCIe*8+ slots for expansion (PCIe*1 is always there).

(4) A mainstream-priced motherboard from top vendors is preferred.

Comment: Nothing wrong with DIY; it is accepted here, but this site is not exclusively DIY. See https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help & https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

Here are kit form suggestions for you:

The high performance Ryzen APU of the [ASRock DeskMini A300](http://www.asrock.com/nettop/AMD/DeskMini%20A300%20Series/#Specification) single board computer provides 60Hz vertical resolution in 4K video from its HDMI 2.0 video output and will use up to 3200 MHz DDR4 RAM, thereby meeting your requirements 1 and 2. Here are [two](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/asrock-deskmini-a300-pc-barebones,6109.html) [reviews](https://www.anandtech.com/show/14251/asrock-deskmini-a300-review-an-affordable-diy-amd-ryzen-minipc).

Intel's [Extreme NUC 9](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/nuc/kits/nuc9i7qnx.html) SBC-chassis-CPU kits have similar capabilities with  Intel® Core™ processors ranging from [i5-9300H](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191075/intel-core-i5-9300h-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html), [i7-9750H](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191045/intel-core-i7-9750h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-50-ghz.html), [i7-9850H](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191047/intel-core-i7-9850h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html), [i9-9980HK](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/192990/intel-core-i9-9980hk-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html), to the [E-2286M](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/192993/intel-xeon-e-2286m-processor-16m-cache-2-40-ghz.html), which ticks the boxes. Here are [CPU comparisons](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=192993,191047,191045,192990).

Comment: What I asked for is CPU and motherboard for DIY (maybe I didn't make that very clear). And I didn't mention price (sorry for that) - main stream price is needed, not high end boards. That's my fault and since you asked for then I vote it anyway.

Comment: Reworked to provide another mainstream priced kit; your desire to get 3GHz performance from DDR4 seems to be a major stumbling block, as many SBCs I find fail on that criteria alone.

Comment: Please also see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for the use of the checkmark  (✅) below the arrowheads.